# captureOutput stops being called after switching CIFilters

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I use this function to change CIFilter on my camera preview. It works as it should, but somehow after switching several filters, captureOutput stops being called and the preview is stuck on the last image captured. It does not return on my "guard let filter". The app does not crash - when I close the camera, and reopen it, it works again.

How can I prevent that behaviour?

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    guard let filter = Filters[FilterNames[currentFilter]] else
    {
        return
    }

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let cameraImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

    filter!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let filteredImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        self.imageView.image = filteredImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the system can't keep up with the rendering of the images. `UIImageView` is not meant to display new images at 30 frames per second while also adding the filtering on top of that.

A much more efficient way would be to render directly into an `MTKView`. I encourage you to check out the [AVCamFilter example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) to see how this can be done.